# No me asigna resultado de ajax afterShowForm

Tags: jqgrid

Tengo un jqgrid con las columnas siguientes

```
                    colModel:[
                        {label: 'ID',name: 'u.usuario_id',width: 75,key: true,editable: true,editrules: {required: false}},
                        {label: 'User',name: 'u.usuario_user',width: 120,searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'ne', 'ew', 'cn'] },editable: true},
                        {label: 'Nombre',name: 'usuario_name',width: 450,editable: true,searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'ne', 'ew', 'cn'] },editable: true},
                        {label: 'Tipo1',name: 'usuario_tipo',width: 20,editable: true},
                        {label: 'Tipo',name: 'tipo_user_nombre',width: 100,editable: true,edittype: "select"},
```

Cuando Genero el formulacion de edicion, quiero que dependiendo de del valor de la columna "usuario_tipo" atravez de ajax genere el html de la columna "tipo_user_nombre" que seria un Select.

En la consola si puedo ver que llama la pagina lista_tipo_usr.php y no generar error pero al regresar el valor al campo con:
$("#tipo_user_nombre").removeAttr("disabled").html(tipoasp);

no lo asigna

```
                    {
                        //new record form
                        //width: 700,
                        closeAfterAdd: true,
                        recreateForm: true,
                        viewPagerButtons: false,
                        beforeShowForm : function(e) {
                            var form = $(e[0]);
                            form.closest('.ui-jqdialog').find('.ui-jqdialog-titlebar')
                            .wrapInner('<div class="widget-header" />')
                            style_edit_form(form);
                        },
                        afterShowForm: permisos_lista
                    },
```

````
function permisos_lista() {
  updateCityCallBack($("#usuario_tipo").val(), false);
}

function updateCityCallBack(tipo, setselected) {
    
  var current = $("#grid-table").jqGrid('getRowData', $("#grid-table")[0].p.selrow).usuario_tipo;

  $("#usuario_tipo").attr("disabled", "true");
  jQuery("#grid-table").jqGrid('hideCol', ["usuario_tipo"]);
  $("#tipo_user_nombre")
    .html("<option value=''>Loading tipos...</option>")
    .attr("disabled", "disabled");

  $.ajax({
    url: "assets/lista_tipo_user.php?permiso=" + tipo,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (tipoasp) {
        $("#tipo_user_nombre")
        .removeAttr("disabled")
        .html(tipoasp);
      if (setselected) {
        $("#tipo_user_nombre").val(current);
      }
    }
  });
} ```
````